# Problem in Executing Mulesoft Batch Component

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mulesoft, mule-esb

I am facing problem in executing batch functionality in MuleSoft 4, I am trying to print the final payload but I am not able to print the final processed payload.Request anyone to help on the same .The code xml is given below .

Thanks.

**Code XML :**

```
<http:listener-config name="parentListener" doc:name="HTTP Listener config" doc:id="fbfff994-e442-42eb-84f7-0d6481ef1198" basePath="/" >
    <http:listener-connection host="0.0.0.0" port="8085" />
</http:listener-config>
<http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_configuration" doc:name="HTTP Request configuration" doc:id="742dd6a4-706e-473d-96f9-9719f34ed2b6" >
    <http:request-connection host="0.0.0.0" port="8086" />
</http:request-config>
<flow name="parent" doc:id="a8cb06bf-866d-4ec6-9f9f-0f492cc05044" >
    <scheduler doc:name="Scheduler" doc:id="c2a54ae1-7de0-4daf-962c-99a5eef5b78a" >
        <scheduling-strategy >
            <fixed-frequency frequency="10000"/>
        </scheduling-strategy>
    </scheduler>
    <set-payload value="#[['Apple','Banana']]" doc:name="[Apple,Banana]" doc:id="5694f264-e91d-4f2e-81aa-1267cb45f250" />
    <batch:job jobName="processRecordsBatch_Job" doc:id="c3290b63-08ba-4abc-a963-02089df89b7a" >
        <batch:process-records >
            <batch:step name="Batch_Step1" doc:id="79158da3-251b-46ec-b276-0421308fe34c" >
                <set-payload value='"1" ++ payload' doc:name="Step One" doc:id="8cb8905c-4e62-4115-995f-5416ac3a26bd" />
            </batch:step>
            <batch:step name="Batch_Step2" doc:id="00e4f7a3-83a8-46be-8b58-9e5d38850fec" >
                <set-payload value='"2"  ++ payload' doc:name='"StepTwo" ' doc:id="41a80eda-d4db-4a6a-9b0e-b79fade09f45" />
            </batch:step>
        </batch:process-records>
        <batch:on-complete >
            <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="56feea1f-6e23-4979-b66b-9d08037b56ef" message='#[payload]'/>
        </batch:on-complete>
    </batch:job>
</flow>
```

**Flow Screenshot:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will not see the 'output' of the batch because the batch scope doesn't return. The batch scope is processed asynchronously with respect to the flow, and doesn't return a value.

You can add loggers in the On Complete stage to print the results of the batch process execution (records processed, failures, etc).

Comment: I got the payload error.Thanks.My main intention is to see the processed payload out of Batch job, could you please help me to see it ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got successful in printing the final output after successful processing of records through it .Screenshot of it is given below . The solution is if we add one more logger component in step 2 as last component we can see the complete output .[image]